# static ip to a freebsd server

Tags: freebsd, ip, mac-address

I have

`Comcast cable <====> modem <===> router <===> freebsd server`

My `freebsd server` is connected to wireless router via a network cable.

What I want to do is, to have a static ip for the server.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set static IP address in FreeBSD in `/etc/rc.conf` file. First you need to know what is name of your network interface that you want to configure. Use `ifconfig` to list all network interfaces, when you find it add following line to `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
ifconfig_INTERFACE_NAME="inet IP_ADDRESS netmask NETMASK"
```

for example:

```
ifconfig_dc0="inet 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0"
```

Comment: And default gateway in `/etc/rc.conf`: `defaultrouter="192.168.0.1"`